# How can I create nested fullpagejs structure?

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I want to create a nested structure using fullpagejs. When it comes to b it has to slide its contents one by one. But as you can see when it comes to b, it skips 2 content. I can't find anything about how to do this.

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  sectionsColor: ['tomato', 'royalblue', 'green', 'pink']
});

new fullpage('#fullpage2', {
  sectionsColor: ['gray', 'dodgerblue', 'teal']
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.8/fullpage.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section a">A</div>
  <div class="section" id="fullpage2">
    <div class="section e">E</div>
    <div class="section f">F</div>
    <div class="section g">G</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section c">C</div>
  <div class="section d">D</div>
</div>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/dev/src/fullpage.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not create sections inside sections. 
Only horizontal slides inside sections.

You are probably looking for something like the [Scroll Horizontally extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html).

In order to create sections, you can find more info in the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) with plenty of [examples too](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples).